# How do I update AndroidManifest.xml after changing package name?

Tags: java, android

I had to rename my package after unsuccessfully uploading to the Google Play Store.  I am using Java.  But now the app builds correctly but crashes immediately when running on the emulator. From searching on here and YouTube it seems my issue is with the manifest.

This is my manifest currently:
[link to image of manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK3fL.png)

Comment: Add crash logs with specific details.

Comment: Try to add the full package path to your activity name.

Answer (score 0):

**Add your package in your manifest file**

[image]

**And write your activity name like this**

[image]